# Extract control input from matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices

I have this expression:
\begin{equation}
[\dots]\cdot C\cdot A^T
\end{equation}
In which C is a diagonal matrix with a control input vector $[c_1 \:c_2 \:c_3\:c_4]$ in its diagonal:
\begin{equation}
[\dots]\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
c_1& 0& 0 &0\\
0 & c_2 & 0&0\\
0 & 0 & c_3&0 \\
0 & 0 & 0&c_4
\end{bmatrix}\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
a& d&g&l\\
b & e & h&m\\
c & f & i&n
\end{bmatrix}^T
\end{equation}
I want to extract the control vector from the matrix multiplication such that:
\begin{equation}
[\dots]\cdot C\cdot A^T=[\dots]\cdot A^T \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
c_1\\
c_2\\
c_3\\
c_4
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What is $[...]$? Also the right matrix in the second formula probably should not be transposed.

Comment: $[\cdots ]$ is a group of other matrices of dimension $n \times 4$

Comment: $\mathbf{c}=C\cdot\left(\array{1\\1\\1\\1}\right)$ if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: Yes. $\textbf{c}$ is the control input